# Passing data from a handler to another. very basic issue about OOP

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, oop

This may be a really basic question to experienced programmers but I started on VB6, and now I'm trying to accomplish same stuff on C# which is object oriented.

*Suppose I have a class with a method to add two numbers on textboxes and I run that in the click handler of a button (Doesn't matter if it is static or not), then I have the result and I display it on the screen (maybe in another textbox), the user click another button, **how do I recover the result on the other button handler?, what's the best practice?**, I know I can read the result on the textbox, but if the result was displayed on a Messagebox.Show or in console?.*

**What's the best practice to save results instead of using helper textboxes or global variables?**

On VB6 I use invisible textboxes, so my forms looks really messy, but thats the way to there.

**Using C# + XAML + WPF**

Comment: Not helping friend, what I really want is to know if there's  a  way to pass data from one scope to another like I see it there is only: 1) Global variables or 2)reading UI elements.... Thanks !

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction?, here's what I said to @H.B.: I'm working with the MVVM but if I have let's say a DataTable bind DataGrid, my DataTable only exist in the scope where I generate it, so to manipulate the data in the DataGrid from other scope I need to use the DataGrid which is accessible from the other scope. then generate a DataTable, load the info from the DataGrid, manipulate the DT and then put all the changed data back into the Datagrid again. is there a way to keep that original DataTable? instead to have to load the info from the DataGrid?,  how do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually that is what a model is for. It is the data-state of what is shown (and more, as some information may not be displayed at all times or just used as utility). The view often has a reference to the model which you then can access in the handlers and manipulate.

I'd suggest reading up on design patterns like Model-View-Controller and for WPF specifially Model-View-ViewModel.

Also, WPF has a few powerful mechanics like [data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which makes synchronizing your data with the view a lot easier, do not treat your view as a model.

Comment: I'm working with the MVVM but if I have let's say a DataTable bind DataGrid, my DataTable only exist in the scope where I generate it, so to manipulate the data in the DataGrid from other scope I need to use the DataGrid which is accessible from the other scope. then generate a DataTable, load the info from the DataGrid, manipulate the DataTable and then put all the changed data back into the Datagrid again. is there a way to keep that original DataTable? instead to have to load the info from the DataGrid?

Comment: @OTANO: You use data binding to synchronize your data table with the `DataGrid`, then you just need to access the data table. You should never get data from UI elements directly. Also if the data table is not accessible you are doing something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: I think that my problem comes at the scope level, because I don't know how to retrive data from an object that was created in another scope, buttons handlers for example. if Ui elements and global variables are not the answer I need to look for something else, it will be very difficult to develop multiwindow apps fighting with this every time, I'll check to see if there's a way to keep the binding ...

Comment: @OTANO: If you need a global model, then i usually create an instance variable on the `App` class. The current app can always be accessed via `App.Current` (returns an `Application` by default, so you need to cast it to your `App` class to access the property).